# Are these diagrams the same?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, electroweak

When computing the propagator of the $Z$ boson at one-loop level in the Standard Model, should we consider both of these two diagrams (where $\varphi^\pm$ are the charged Goldstone bosons) or are they the same diagram and should only be considered once?

[image: Diagrams]

Answer (score 0):

Think about how Feynman diagrams originate from the perturbative expansion. These two diagrams will come from different terms in the expansion, so they are not the same.